# ¿Cómo establecer una ruta de un archivo PHP en JS?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo los siguientes archivos en la raiz de mi proyecto:

reloj.php

js/ac/live.js

tutipo/tutipo.php

En el archivo tutipo.php estoy haciendo la llamada del archivo js/ac/live.js este es mi codigo:

```
    <?php 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" id="html">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tutipo</title>
    
</head>
<body  >

 <script src="../js/ac/live.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

En el archivo live.js es un código JS donde hago una petición y traigo los datos de reloj.php (aquí solo se muestra la hora actual). Cabe aclarar que se tiene mas código por debajo, pero no es necesario ponerlo.

```
function muestraReloj () {
         fetch("reloj.php") 
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => reloj.value = data); 
         var fechaYHoraAc = reloj.value;
```

En consola al hacer la petición me sale error 404, que no encuentra ese archivo, ejemplo:

http://localhost:82/Tips/tutipo/reloj.php

Esto es por que no encuentra el archivo php reloj.php, dentro de la carpeta tutipo puesto que el archivo reloj.php esta en raiz. Se que puedo poner " ../ "  para llegar al archivo pero el problema es que como tengo otros archivos en raiz que tambien ocupan el sript entonces esos archivos no encontrarian el archivo reloj.php y si establezco toda la ruta completa se tendría alguna complicación, ya que mi servidor tiene certificado ssl y si por algun motivo buscan la pagina como http y no https entonces no funciona el script. Alguien sabe como resolver esto?. Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de los namesSpaces en php aqui tienes una pequeña guia https://diego.com.es/namespaces-en-php

Comment: Estás olvidando que las rutas son relativas al documento HTML mostrado (`tutipo.php`), por lo que la ruta relativa sería `../reloj.php`. Además, como el recurso está en el directorio raíz, podrías usar `/reloj.php`. PD: Creo que tu pregunta está mal y debería decir: *¿Cómo establecer una ruta a un archivo JavaScript desde PHP?* aunque, obviamente, es problema de HTML, no de PHP.

Comment: Gracias por comentar sus sugerencias, las tomare en cuenta